# how to get a picture from a postgresql database

Tags: c#, image, postgresql, get, npgsql

i want to select a picture that save as a large object in a postgresql database.

i know i use lo_export to do this.

but there is a problem: i want to save this picture directly to my computer because i cant access the files that save on Server using lo_export

(i think that is best for me if picture transfer to my computer by a select query)

Comment: my c# code, it use Npgsql dll to connect to database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't exactly know my way around C# but the Npgsql Manual has an example sort of like this of writing a `bytea` column to a file:

```
command = new NpgsqlCommand("select blob from t where id = 1);", conn);
Byte[] result = (Byte[])command.ExecuteScalar();

FileStream fs = new FileStream(args[0] + "database", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(new BufferedStream(fs));

bw.Write(result);
bw.Flush();
fs.Close();
bw.Close();
```

So you just read it out of the database pretty much like any other column and write it to a local file. The example is about half way down the page I linked to, just search for "bytea" and you'll find it.

**UPDATE**: For large objects, the process appears to be similar but less SQL-ish. The manual (as linked to above) includes a few large object examples:

```
NpgsqlTransaction t = Polacz.BeginTransaction();

LargeObjectManager lbm = new LargeObjectManager(Polacz);
LargeObject lo = lbm.Open(takeOID(idtowaru),LargeObjectManager.READWRITE); //take picture oid from metod takeOID

byte[] buf = new byte[lo.Size()];
buf = lo.Read(lo.Size());

MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
ms.Write(buf,0,lo.Size());

// ...

Image zdjecie = Image.FromStream(ms);
```

Search the manual for "large object" and you'll find it.

Comment: my picture  field's type in database is 'lo' which means Large Object and i can't change its type. i have the size of picture too in my database.

Comment: @user715878: Sorry about that. I added an update with some notes on large objects, the manual I linked to covers those too.

Comment: nicely done, my problem has been solved by your updated solution. tnx tnx tanx :)

Comment: excuse me ! can you explain that how I should insert a large object (picture) to my database (by using above method)

Comment: @user715878: There's an example of that in the [User's Manual](http://npgsql.projects.postgresql.org/docs/manual/UserManual.html).

Comment: Note that you must use NpgsqlTransaction as in this example to have an error free code. [Re: Invalid large object descriptor : 0](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/002701c49d7e$0f059240$d604460a@zaphod)

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with C# but if you've contrib/dblink around and better access to a separate postgresql server, this might work:

1. select large object from bad db server.
2. copy large object into good db server using dblink.
3. lo_export on good db server.

Comment: this solution isn't possible in my case. i have only bad db server ;)

Comment: Don't you have a hosting account somewhere?

Comment: no, this project is in a government center with political security limitation

Answer (score 0):

If your pictures don't exceed 1GB (or if you don't access only parts of the bytes) then using `bytea` is the better choice to store them.

A lot of SQL GUI tools allow to directly download (even view) the content of bytea columns directly