# How to convert object in byte[] c#

Tags: c#, postgresql, c#-4.0, byte

**CONVERT OBJECT TO BYTE[]**

Hello how are you? I'm having difficulties in converting an object (returned by a query to the Postgres database) to byte[], I test in several different ways but I can't get the total size of the array stored in the database referring to the image. I have a single image saved in the database, and in each way I try to retrieve it, the byte[] comes with a different size depending on how I do the conversion from object to byte[]. The biggest array size I got was length = 42, the image has length = 675486. I've tried these ways.

```
 using (conexao)
        {
            string sQL = " SELECT p.photo_img " +
                        " FROM empresa as e, photo as p " +
                        " WHERE e.empresa_img = " + id + " AND " +
                        " e.empresa_img = p.photo_id; ";

            using (var command = new NpgsqlCommand(sQL, conexao))
            {
                byte[] productImageByte = null;
                conexao.Open();
                var rdr = command.ExecuteReader();

                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    productImageByte = (byte[])rdr[0];
                }
                rdr.Close();
                if (productImageByte != null)
                {
                    using (MemoryStream productImageStream = new MemoryStream(productImageByte))
                    {
                        ImageConverter imageConverter = new System.Drawing.ImageConverter();
                        pct_Imagem.Image = imageConverter.ConvertFrom(productImageByte) as System.Drawing.Image;
                    }
                }
            }

        }
```

The result of this was length = 13

```
    private void dgv_empresa_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        int id = Convert.ToInt32(dgv_empresa.SelectedCells[0].OwningRow.Cells[9].Value);
        if (id != 0)
        {
            try
            {
                string query = " SELECT p.photo_img " +
                        " FROM empresa as e, photo as p " +
                        " WHERE e.empresa_img = " + id + " AND " +
                        " e.empresa_img = p.photo_id; ";

                conexao.Open();
                DataTable dados = new DataTable();
                NpgsqlDataAdapter adaptador = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(query, conexao);
                adaptador.Fill(dados);

                if (dados.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (DataRow linha in dados.Rows)
                    { 
                        byte[] data = ObjectToByteArray(linha[0]);

                        var imagem = (Image)new ImageConverter().ConvertFrom(data);
                        pct_Imagem.Image = imagem;
                    }
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                conexao.Close();
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Erro no Banco de Dados!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
            finally
            {
                conexao.Close();
            }
         }
    }

    byte[] ObjectToByteArray(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
            return null;
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            bf.Serialize(ms, obj);
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
     }
```

The result of this was length = 42

**These last two brought me the best results. But still, it's not a valid byte array. Can someone help me?**

Comment: Do not use string concatenation to create an SQL command. Use parameterized statements. See [why it's a bad idea and how to fix it](//bobby-tables.com).

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for the tip, I will police myself not to make this mistake again... Thank you very much!!!  @gunr2171

Comment: You have [already asked this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72665631/7444103). First of all, you need to show how you're saving this image to your database. Then, don't use a DataTable and a DataAadapter to retrieve the image, just execute a DataReader, get its first Column (since you're getting just one), cast the Column's Value to `byte[]` -- This assumes the Image has been saved - correctly - as a byte array. It also assumes that your query is correct. -- Maybe post the Table definition.

Comment: Maybe this can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5932193/how-to-get-a-picture-from-a-postgresql-database

Comment: As already mentioned, use this post [How to insert and retrieve image from PostgreSql using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46128132/7444103) as guide. -- Not very useful to thank people for their suggestions when you don't follow them in any way.

Comment: Jimi, I did test the suggestion you presented to me in this link. But it returns me only 13 bytes, the amount returned by it is even better than what I managed to return. So, I'm sorry but this link didn't help me much... I'm starting to believe that it may be a question of dll equal to what is written in the chat of the link you sent, I updated the NPGSQL version as suggested in the link you sent, but didn't solve it either

Comment: Trying again, but for the last time: you need to post the code that saves the image into your database, the Table definition and also try to put into practice all the suggestions you have received (not just mine), e.g., that's not the way to build a query (at all), that's not the way to use a Connection in .Net. A Connection object must not be stored, it must be opened and closed in the same procedure that performs the query, along with all the other objects -- Use Parameters to build a query, don't use a DataTable or a DataAdapter for this, execute a DataReader and get the result from it.

Comment: The post I linked is all you need to make this work. Try to follow it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do, what I needed to adjust to not use Connetion, but create and discard in each block that was to be used

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

you can use this method that I serialized the class into `JSON` text and then converted it to `byte[]`. You can either serialize it to XML

```
private async Task<byte[]> CreateByteArrayAsync(object obj)
        {
            using var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            await using var writer = new StreamWriter(memoryStream);
            var jsonText = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
            await writer.WriteAsync(jsonText);
            await writer.FlushAsync();

            return memoryStream.ToArray();        }
```

Comment: Hello, I tested the way you indicated, and the result was a little strange, it only returned 1 byte

Comment: @alysonpereira Can you provide more information? I just tested the code, And it's working. I suggest tracing the code and debugging the`jsonText`. To be sure, you can use JsonConvert from `Newtonsoft.Json` NuGet

Comment: @alysonpereira it was using async methods but not awaiting them. Proposing update.